# JasperReports Server : Please wait

Tags: remote-access, jasperserver

When I accessed Jasper Reports from Remote Jasper server.

The Reports is being shown in background, where as it shows Please Wait pop-up on fore-ground for indefinite time period.

I have tried `IE8` and `IE10` to check it and works fine for `Chrome and Firefox.`

```
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/ (working fine) 

http://<LAN IP ADDRESS where JAsperReports are deployed>:8080/jasperserver/ (facing problem)
```

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat is probably not listening to any other interface than the localhost one.

Check the servers.xml in tomcat's configuration and search for the "Connector" tag. Create a new one, with a new port. Check also tomcat's documentation if that new connector is behind a reverse proxy. Tomcat has appropriate properties for that tag to handle SSL Reverse proxy. That might be handy to you.

Hope I pointed you to the right path. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JasperServer 5.5 this problem might be connnected to your IE using compatibility mode. Please check with F12 (developer tools) which browser mode is active.

Answer (score 0):

Go the windows firewall settings and [create a new 'inbound/outbound' rule](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7) to allow connections to the port 8080.

Just worked for me.