# Can't open JasperReports Server from a remote pc

Tags: remote-access, jasperserver

I am trying to access JasperReports Server on another pc on the same network but I always get a "page cannot be open" message. I mainly use Safari, but I also tried Firefox and Chrome but it still wasn't working. I was trying to access it in the following way:

```
http://<ip address>:8080/jasperserver/
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What happens when you ping <ip address>?

Comment: @Paulb Sorry for not replying earlier. When I ping, I get a response. I've even used the database on the remote pc for the data source for my jasper reports. That works perfectly.

Comment: something here for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058520/jasperreports-server-please-wait